# Уведомление пользователя о выполнении операции сохранения в БД

Tags: c#, gui, база-данных

Для доступа к БД использую Entity Framework. Процесс сохранения данных, введенных пользователем, не мгновенный. Как сделать уведомление о том, что процесс выполняется?
Варианты изменить курсор, показать прогресс бар - это все частности. Важно понять саму идею.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проект .net 4.5, используйте асинхронный метод сохранения SaveChangesAsync(). При этом можете оповещать пользователя о начале и конце сохранения любым способом. Если же не 4.5, то тут все сложнее, есть библиотека [Microsoft Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/), которая позволяет использовать async в net 4, но сами разработчики не рекомендуют использовать ее в продакшене, также для ее корректной работы для windows xp понадобиться патч. Второй способ отказаться от долгоживущего контекста и использовать Ваш способ с BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел два простых решения:

1. Однопоточное и совсем простое.

   ```
   public void MyMethod(Items items)
   {
       Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
       DataBase.Save(itmes);
       Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
   }
   ```
2. Многопоточное, в котором используется класс [System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Но в моем случае, с ним ничего не получилось, так как есть данные, которые нужно блокировать, иначе получается доступ к ним из нескольких потоков. В итоге в базе данных оказывается непредсказуемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

[Есть цикл статей для wpf (с использование шаблона MVVM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/ee532098%28en-us%29.aspx?sdmr=StephenCleary&sdmi=authors) - описано и как сделать уведомления. Есть и на русском...